# Transformer voltage formula

Tags: power, transformer

How is the output voltage 5 V if the ratio is 5:1 and the input voltage is 36 - 72 VDC in this [Wurth transformer datasheet](https://www.we-online.com/components/products/datasheet/750310926.pdf)?

Nominally we would see 48 V. Vs/Vp = Ns/Np, Vs = 48/5 = 9.6 V

Answer (score 2):

A flyback 'transformer' is not used in the same way as a normal transformer.

It is a pair of coupled inductors.

During the first phase, the primary inductor is 'charged up' with current, storing magnetic energy in the core. The voltage generated in the secondary during this phase is usually blocked with a diode.

During the second phase, the primary inductor is open-circuited. The energy stored in the core reverses the voltage on both windings. The secondary voltage rises until it reaches the voltage of the storage capacitors downstream of the diode after the secondary, and then it starts to dump the stored energy into those capacitors at their voltage. The voltage generated in the primary during this phase is tolerated by proper design, for instance by using a primary switch with a high enough withstanding voltage.

The turns ratio still applies, but as the windings are used alternately, there is a further factor that affects the voltage ratio.

Answer (score 1):

The transformer you linked is optimised for a CCM Flyback with said input voltage range and with a switching frequency range of 250-400 kHz.

The transformer in a flyback regulator should be thought of as a coupled inductor, although part of the operation is still transformer action.

Basically, to "keep" the output voltage constant the controller adjusts the duty cycle for different input voltages and loading levels. You need to study the operation of DCM and CCM flyback for better understanding.

Answer (score 0):

The only mention of 5 volts is in the table below: -

[image]

And the typical application mentioned is that of a flyback power supply running in CCM (continuous conduction mode). For it to run in continuous conduction mode (or even discontinuous conduction mode) it has to have certain components placed around it: -

- An output diode and smoothing capacitor
- A primary side MOSFET to control the on/off duty cycle of the primary
- A circuit that controls the MOSFET to keep the output DC voltage regulated

Without those things, you can just regard it as a conventional transformer.

> *How is the output voltage 5V if the ratio is 5:1 and the input voltage
> is 36 - 72 VDC in this Wurth Transformer Data Sheet?*

Because the control circuit and MOSFET set an appropriate pulse width modulation duty cycle that, in effect, adjusts the input supply voltage so that 5 volts DC appears at the output.